# How to set React component state and props from browser

Tags: google-chrome-extension, reactjs

Is there a possibility to access and set the state and props of an existing React component through the browser (from inside another script or through console)?

I know there is a way with Angular to access the scope and change variables, but with React I haven't been able to find a way.

I would assume there must be some way because the React Developer Tools extension from Facebook is able to get all the information (Props, State, Component, Event Listeners) from the React components on the page, with the possibility to change them.

If there is a possibility to do this through JavaScript, which would be the way to do it?

Comment: As is, it's too broad to answer, and "Is there a possibility" is answered with a "yes" in the question proper.

Comment: Well. Still. How "look at [facebook/react-devtools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools)" is not an answer?

Comment: What are you trying to do (or more importantly, why)? I think the tools just set props/state directly and then force an update on the component. You shouldn't use this technique as part of an application.

Answer (score 27):

If you have the [React devtools extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en), you can access the React scope via your browser console with `$r`.

First, select the component you wanna act on in the React devtools tab:

[image]

Then, use `$r` to act on the component, for example read state with `$r.state` or set state with `$r.setState({ ... })` :

[image]

Comment: This is not possible with latest React Tool 4.4.0 anyone know a way with the new devtools?

Comment: @XwrisStoixeia I version 4.8.2 of the React Dev Tools and I can still use this option in the console.

Comment: `setState()` wasn't working for my particular situation, but I was still able to modify the state property directly. Just remember to trigger a rerender if you do it this way.

Comment: I am building a chrome extension, do I need to package the react dev tool inside my extension to call the method setState on the methods?

Comment: This answer appears to be specific to a brand (maybe even version) of browser.

Answer (score 2):

To set a react components's state from the browser, you can bind a function to the window object that will trigger the set state.

In the react component's constructor, you can do this.

```
constructor (props){
    super(props);
    window.changeComponentState = (stateObject) => {
        this.setState ({stateObject});
    }
}
```

In the browser console you can do this.

```
window.changeComponentState ({a:'a'});
```

WARNING: This is anti-pattern. This will work, but you should never never do this.

Comment: Same problem as the other answer. This isn't about React components you have control over. It's about injecting code in a page with pre-existing React components - where you can't change constructors.

Answer (score -3):

To set the state from your browser, stick this somewhere in your component, like in `render()`:

```
  globalSetState = function(state){this.setState(state)}.bind(this);
```

Note: It's important to leave off the `var`, as this is what makes the defined function globally accessible.

You can now call `globalSetState({x: 'y'})` in your console.

**Warning**: This is mad ugly, and, like `console.log()` for debugging, should be deleted in your live app.

Comment: Er, you don't understand the question. It's a question about setting state of components that you did not author, overriding them using a Chrome Extension.