# How to setstate for a variable on React webpage from Cefsharp browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate, cefsharp

I have a React webpage embed in `Cefsharp` browser. I'm trying to login to the website when the app loads with a generic username and password.

I'm able to populate the input elements with values using:

```js
EvaluateScriptAsync (document.getElementById('email').value= "abc@email.com")
```

However, looks like the value is not recognized by the Login method because they are not getting bound to state variable (for ex: `this.state.username` is not getting set to `abc@email.com`). Is there a way to `setstate` for a variable using `EvaluateScriptAsync`?

Here is what I've tried:

```js
public MainWindow()
        {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            settings.CachePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) +
                                 @"\CEF\cache";
            CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings);
            InitializeComponent();
            Browser.LoadingStateChanged += async (sender, args) =>
            {
                //Wait for the Page to finish loading
                if (args.IsLoading == false)
                {
                    await Browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementById('email').value='abc@email.com';");
                    await Browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementById('password').value='password'";);
                    await Browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementById('login').click()");
                }
            };
        }
```

Comment: This is what I have so far. I am just trying to embed the react website in cefsharp browser.

Comment: I have never used `cefsharp`. So, where do you write *that* (`Browser.LoadingStateChanged ....` ) code; in a React component?

Comment: I updated the code. It is not on React component, but the wpf side.

Comment: EvaluateScriptAsync is very much like executing code in DevTools. How does your code work when run via DevTools in Chrome?

Comment: I have the same error in Devtools as well

Comment: Broaden your search, what you are attempting to do isn't CefSharp specific. A quick search yields https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218664/how-to-set-react-component-state-and-props-from-browser